# Designing support for BT in a car's audio system

Tags: automotive, bluetooth, digital-audio

We are designing a pre-amplifier outputting I2S and need to stream this to a car's audio system via Bluetooth. We have tried a module from TinySine, but it turned out it can only connect to headphones. It's not seen by the car and can't be selected for connection because it has no client (that was the explanation we got.)

As I understand, a car needs both master and client protocols to connect. Can anyone point out a design solution/module/chip-set to make a connection to a car?

If I2S isn't available, we can try to convert it to another digital format.

#### in short

We need to send an I2S stream -> Bluetooth -> Car Audio system.
We are interested in how to stream to the car's audio system over Bluetooth.

So after more investigation the codec must be minimum SBC, but aptX, and aptX HD are great if it's possible. As far I understand, the Bluetooth profiles are minimum: A2DP and HSP.

#### I'm not asking for a product.

We need to understanding what is needed to connect to a car's audio system over Bluetooth. Are there any chipsets available? Any reference designs? Documentation?

Comment: I have reopen this after viewing its edited form and only then noted that it had previously  been closed by a moderator. I note that as it stands it appears to be a request for a method rather than an IC or module but it was not at all clear initially. It may yet the deemed to be site unsuitable.

Comment: I note that the comment which was not there when I saw the post that some people had voted to close it because they had not bothered to read the whole questions is inappropriate liable  to be incorrect. That sort of comment is better not made. There are definitely people here who can answer the question.

Comment: The comment was pure frustration and written meanwhile you opened it again. If I had seen you open it, I wouldn't have written any comment at all. It has happened before that people only reads the first paragraph. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Max - I sympathize and I'm aware that votes to close are not always as rational as they might ideally  be. However, rational and objective statements of why what you want suits site rules is better than criticising others. This is because you may or may not be correct but you will get extra negative reaction from some people as a consequence. Also, person directed (here semi anonymous) comments often rapidly escalate into unallowed arguments.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you are designing a Bluetooth amplifier and you want to receive I2S audio stream from car head unit to your Bluetooth amplifier? The problem is, both the car head unit and yiur TinySine modules are Bluetooth audio amplifiers so they receive audio. They do not send audio. I do not recall seeing a car head unit that transmits audio out via Bluetooth. They receive audio just fine from Bluetooth transmitters like mobile phones.

Comment: No the opposite. We are developing a pre-amplifier with an ADC outputting I2S. We want to stream that I2S to the car's audio system. I will update the question.

Comment: You need to consider and probably research codecs. There are number of them in existence, and they likely vary in quality and how widely they are supported. You should take a look at this and at least make a shortlist of which ones seem to be acceptable. Once you did that, you can start thinking about implementation options.

Comment: Note that I2S is essentially PCm (lossless, uncompressed), and while it probably IS possible to get that amount of data over bluetooth, it is pretty wasteful and may not be necessary for your application (which you have not described). You might be better using a compressed format, but that implies converting the data stream before sending it over BT. These are design decisions and tradeoffs that you have to figure out before you can choose a platform. More info: https://www.soundguys.com/understanding-bluetooth-codecs-15352/

Comment: I updated the question. It seems like we need minimum A2DP SBC.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=microcontroller+bluetooth+i2s) help you?

Comment: By the way, this is my first hit: https://github.com/pschatzmann/ESP32-A2DP
Note: the direction can also be reversed.

Comment: We have tried ordinary streaming to speakers, but that isn't enough for a car. A car needs to select the transmitter. A speaker is accepting any connection in pair mode and differ in that way from a car that needs to select a specific device. The problem is that internet is full of project connecting to a speaker or headphones, but that isn't enough for a car.